# ajax not working in IE8 and above

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, internet-explorer-8

i have using this ajax call for populatig values its is workong fine in all other browsers but not in iE 8

```
  function makedate() {
             var value1="";
             var value2=""; 
             var value3="";
              var xmlHttpRequest = getXMLHttpRequest();

              xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = makedateStateHandler(xmlHttpRequest);

              $("#button").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
             var  date= document.getElementById("date").value;
             var  value=document.getElementById("value").value;
            // alert(value);
             var Appointmentdateformat= document.getElementById("Appointment").options[document.getElementById("Appointment").selectedIndex].value;
             //alert(Appointmentdateformat);
             var  Location = document.getElementById("Location").options[document.getElementById("Location").selectedIndex].value;
             var  Provider = document.getElementById("Provider").options[document.getElementById("Provider").selectedIndex].value;
             // alert(date+Location+Provider+Appointmentdateformat+value)  ;    
        //& Location="+Location+"&Provider="+Provider
              xmlHttpRequest.open("POST", "ajaXForgetdatesForAppoinment.jsp?date="+date+"&Location="+Location+"&Provider="+Provider+"&Appointmentdateformat="+Appointmentdateformat+"&value="+value, true);
              xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
                  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
              xmlHttpRequest.send(null);
            }
            function makedateStateHandler(xmlHttpRequest) {

                  // an anonymous function returned
                  // it listens to the XMLHttpRequest instance
                  return function() {
                    if (xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 4) {
                      if (xmlHttpRequest.status == 200) {
                          //document.getElementById('loading').style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
                         // $("#select").removeAttr("disabled"); 
                          //alert(xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
                          $("#button").removeAttr("disabled"); 
                        document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML = xmlHttpRequest.responseText;
                      } else {
                       // alert("HTTP error " + xmlHttpRequest.status + ": " + xmlHttpRequest.statusText);
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
```

This is my JSP page from where I am calling this Ajax function

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<%@page import="pojo.AppointmentDetails"%>
<%@page import="pojo.MiniProvider"%>
<%@page import="pojo.MiniFacility"%>
<%@page import="pojo.Patient"%>
<%@page import="pojo.AppoinmentTimedetails"%>
<%@page import="pojo.AppointmentTypes"%>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>GMQ Physician Associates</title>
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style2.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<!-- <![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/basicnifo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/datepicker2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js"></script>

-->
</head>
<%
AppoinmentTimedetails appoinmentTimedetails=null;
Patient patient=new Patient();
patient.setsState("");
AppointmentDetails []appointmentDetails=null;
MiniProvider [] miniProviders=null;
MiniFacility[]miniFacilities =null;
AppointmentTypes []appointmentTypes=null;

miniFacilities=(MiniFacility[])request.getAttribute("miniFacilities"); 
if(miniFacilities==null){
    miniFacilities=new  MiniFacility[1];
    miniFacilities[0]=new MiniFacility();
    miniFacilities[0].setiFacilityId(0);
    miniFacilities[0].setsFacilityName("");

}

miniProviders=(MiniProvider[])request.getAttribute("miniProviders"); 
if(miniProviders==null){
    miniProviders=new   MiniProvider[1];
    miniProviders[0]=new MiniProvider();
    miniProviders[0].setiProviderId(0);
    miniProviders[0].setsProviderName("");

}
appointmentDetails=(AppointmentDetails[])request.getAttribute("appointmentDetails"); 
if(appointmentDetails==null){
 appointmentDetails=new AppointmentDetails[1];
 appointmentDetails[0]=new AppointmentDetails();
 appointmentDetails[0].setsStatus("");
 appointmentDetails[0].setsFacilityName("");
 appointmentDetails[0].setsProviderName("");
 appointmentDetails[0].setsStartTime("");
}
appointmentTypes=(AppointmentTypes[])request.getAttribute("appointmentTypes"); 
if(appointmentTypes==null){
    appointmentTypes=new AppointmentTypes[1];
    appointmentTypes[0]=new AppointmentTypes(); 
    appointmentTypes[0].setiAppointmentTypesId(0);
    appointmentTypes[0].setsCaption("");
}

/*appoinmentTimedetails=(AppoinmentTimedetails)request.getAttribute("appoinmentTimedetails"); 
if(appoinmentTimedetails==null){
    appoinmentTimedetails=new AppoinmentTimedetails();
    appoinmentTimedetails.setsLocation("");
    appoinmentTimedetails.setsProvider("");
    appoinmentTimedetails.setsVisitType("");

}*/

%>

<body>
<div id="main">
  <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="50%"><img src="images/logo.jpg" width="385" height="97" alt="logo" /></td>
      <td width="50%"><img src="images/people.jpg" width="327" height="97" class="m1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><div class="m2">
<a href="#"><div id="home" style="background:url(images/topnav-bt-bg1.png) no-repeat;" class="topnav" onMouseOver="changeBgImage('images/topnav-bt-bg2.png', 'home')" onMouseOut="changeBgImage('images/topnav-bt-bg1.png', 'home')">HOME</div></a>
<a href="#"><div id="service" style="background:url(images/topnav-bt-bg1.png) no-repeat;" class="topnav" onMouseOver="changeBgImage('images/topnav-bt-bg2.png', 'service')" onMouseOut="changeBgImage('images/topnav-bt-bg1.png', 'service')">SERVICES</div></a>
<a href="#"><div id="provider" style="background:url(images/topnav-bt-bg1.png) no-repeat;" class="topnav" onMouseOver="changeBgImage('images/topnav-bt-bg2.png', 'provider')" onMouseOut="changeBgImage('images/topnav-bt-bg1.png', 'provider')">PROVIDER</div></a>
<a href="#"><div id="register" style="background:url(images/topnav-bt-bg1.png) no-repeat;" class="topnav" onMouseOver="changeBgImage('images/topnav-bt-bg2.png', 'register')" onMouseOut="changeBgImage('images/topnav-bt-bg1.png', 'register')">REGISTRATION</div></a>
<a href="#"><div id="faq" style="background:url(images/topnav-bt-bg1.png) no-repeat;" class="topnav" onMouseOver="changeBgImage('images/topnav-bt-bg2.png', 'faq')" onMouseOut="changeBgImage('images/topnav-bt-bg1.png', 'faq')">FAQ</div></a>
<a href="#"><div id="contact" style="background:url(images/topnav-bt-bg1.png) no-repeat;" class="topnav" onMouseOver="changeBgImage('images/topnav-bt-bg2.png', 'contact')" onMouseOut="changeBgImage('images/topnav-bt-bg1.png', 'contact')">CONTACT</div></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="m5">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" class="m3">
    <div class="m3a">Quick Menu</div>
    <div class="m9">
  <a href="Basic_info?action=basic"><div id="basic" style="background:url(images/basic-info-bt1.png) no-repeat;" class="leftnav" onMouseOver="changeBgImage('images/basic-info-bt2.png', 'basic')" onMouseOut="changeBgImage('images/basic-info-bt1.png', 'basic')">Basic Info</div></a>
 <a href="Basic_info?action=appoinments:"><div id="app" style="background:url(images/appointments-bt2.png) no-repeat;" class="leftnav">Appointments</div></a>
 <a href="newMessage.jsp">
 <div id="newmess" style="background:url(images/new-message-bt1.png) no-repeat;" class="leftnav" onMouseOver="changeBgImage('images/new-message-bt2.png', 'newmess')" onMouseOut="changeBgImage('images/new-message-bt1.png', 'newmess')">New Message</div></a>
 <a href="Basic_info?action=inbox:"><div id="inbox" style="background:url(images/inbox-bt1.png) no-repeat;" class="leftnav" onMouseOver="changeBgImage('images/inbox-bt2.png', 'inbox')" onMouseOut="changeBgImage('images/inbox-bt1.png', 'inbox')">Inbox</div></a>
 <a href="Basic_info?action=outbox:"><div id="outbox" style="background:url(images/outbox-bt1.png) no-repeat;" class="leftnav" onMouseOver="changeBgImage('images/outbox-bt2.png', 'outbox')" onMouseOut="changeBgImage('images/outbox-bt1.png', 'outbox')">Outbox</div></a>
 <a href="Basic_info?action=health-summary:"><div id="health" style="background:url(images/health-summary-bt1.png) no-repeat;" class="leftnav" onMouseOver="changeBgImage('images/health-summary-bt2.png', 'health')" onMouseOut="changeBgImage('images/health-summary-bt1.png', 'health')">Health Summary</div></a>
 <a href="Basic_info?action=clinical-summary:"><div id="clinical" style="background:url(images/clinical-summary-bt1.png) no-repeat;" class="leftnav" onMouseOver="changeBgImage('images/clinical-summary-bt2.png', 'clinical')" onMouseOut="changeBgImage('images/clinical-summary-bt1.png', 'clinical')">Clinical Summary</div></a>
 <a href="Basic_info?action=employer-guarantor:"><div id="gurantor" style="background:url(images/employer-gurantor-bt1.png) no-repeat;" class="leftnav" onMouseOver="changeBgImage('images/employer-gurantor-bt2.png', 'gurantor')" onMouseOut="changeBgImage('images/employer-gurantor-bt1.png', 'gurantor')">Employer Guarantor</div></a>
 <a href="Basic_info?action=insurance:"><div id="insurance" style="background:url(images/insurance-bt1.png) no-repeat;" class="leftnav" onMouseOver="changeBgImage('images/insurance-bt2.png', 'insurance')" onMouseOut="changeBgImage('images/insurance-bt1.png', 'insurance')">Insurance</div></a>
 <a href="Basic_info?action=patienthistory:"><div id="history" style="background:url(images/patient-history-bt1.png) no-repeat;" class="leftnav" onMouseOver="changeBgImage('images/patient-history-bt2.png', 'history')" onMouseOut="changeBgImage('images/patient-history-bt1.png', 'history')">Patient History</div></a>
 <a href="Basic_info?action=logout:"><div id="logout" style="background:url(images/logout-bt1.png) no-repeat;" class="leftnav" onMouseOver="changeBgImage('images/logout-bt2.png', 'logout')" onMouseOut="changeBgImage('images/logout-bt1.png', 'logout')">Logout</div></a>











      </div>
    <div class="m8">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" class="m4">
    <div class="m4a">Appointments</div>
    <div class="m6">
    <form action="#" method="post" name="reg" id="reg">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td><div class="m12"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
            <tr>  
              <td style="width:15%;">Location</td>
              <td style="width:35%;"><select name="Location" id="Location" class="drop2">
                <option value="0">-Select-</option>
                 <% for(int i=0;i<miniFacilities.length;i++){%>
                 <option value="<%=miniFacilities[i].getiFacilityId()%>"<%if(patient.getsState().equals(miniFacilities[i].getiFacilityId())){out.println("selected='selected'");} %>><%=miniFacilities[i].getsFacilityName()%></option><% }%>
              </select></td>
              <td style="width:15%;">Provider</td>
              <td width="25%" style="width:35%;"><select name="Provider" id="Provider" class="drop2">
                <option value="">-Select-</option>


                <% for(int i=0;i<miniProviders.length;i++){%>

                 <option value="<%=miniProviders[i].getiProviderId()%>"<%if(patient.getsState().equals(miniProviders[i].getiProviderId())){out.println("selected='selected'");} %>><%=miniProviders[i].getsProviderName()%></option><% }%>
              </select><br><span id="username_warning" style="color:red"></span></br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 

               <td>Appointment Date Format</td>

              <td ><span style="width:35%;">
                <select name="Appointment" id="Appointment" class="drop2" >
                  <option value="0" selected="selected">-Select-</option>
                  <option value="Earliest available date" >Earliest available date</option>
                  <option value="Allow me to pick a Date" >Allow me to pick a Date</option>
                </select>
              </span></td>
              <td id="AppointmentDate">Appointment Date</td>
           <td bgcolor="#F5F5F5" style="width:15%;"><input type="text" name="date" id="date" tabindex="1" class="m10 autocompletehealth" value=""  /></td> 

            <tr>



            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>



              <td><input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="SEARCH" class="bt-press" onclick=""onmouseover="changeBgImage('images/button-bg2.png', 'update')" onmouseout="changeBgImage('images/button-bg.png', 'update')" />

                </td>
            </tr>
            <table id="divId" >

            </table>

             <tr >
             <td></td>
              <td valign="top" style="width:15%;"><br />
            </td>
           </tr>
          </table></div></td>
        </tr>


             <input type="hidden" name="page" value="appoinments2" class="m10" />
             <input type="hidden" name="value" value="" class="m10"  id="value"/>
      </table>
    </form>
    </div><!--
    <div class="m7">&nbsp;<br />
    </div>
    -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--<div class="foot">GMQ Physician Associates, 100-C, Foley, AL 3655 TEL: (456)789-2343 FAX: (456)789-2343</div>
-->
</div>
<script>
var count=0;
$(document).ready(function(){
     //$("#date").hide(); 
     //$("#AppointmentDate").hide(); 

      //  alert("");

        $( "#date" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0 , dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy"});

    });
$("#Appointment").change(function() {


     // alert($(this).val());
      // $("#date").removeAttr("disabled"); 

     // $( "#Appointment" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0 , dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});

          $('#Appointment').live('change', function() {
             // alert($(this).val());
              if ($(this).val() == "Allow me to pick a Date") {
                   $("#mm").show(); 
                 // $("#date").show(); 
                 // $("#AppointmentDate").show();

          $("#date").datepicker({showOn:'both',dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy"}).focus();

          }
      if ($(this).val() == "Earliest available date") {
          $("#mm").hide(); 
                //  $("#date").hide(); 
            //  $("#AppointmentDate").hide();


          }
        });  

    }); 
    $('#next').live('click', function() {
        //alert("next");
        $("#username_warning").empty(); 
        if($('#Provider').val()=="") {


             var username_length; 

             username_length = $("#Provider").val().length; 


             if (username_length <1){ 

                 $("#username_warning").append("Please select a provider"); 
             return false;
        }}
        else  {
            if(count<1)
            {
                //alert(count+"less");
            count=1;
            }
            else
            {
                count=count+1;
                //alert(count+"grater");
            }
            //alert(count);
            $('#value').val(count);

            ///alert($('#value').val()+"count");

            //$("#value").value(count);
            //alert(    $("#value").value());
            makedate();

        }

    }); 
    $('#back').live('click', function() {
    //alert("aaaa");
    $("#username_warning").empty(); 
    if($('#Provider').val()=="") {


         var username_length; 

         username_length = $("#Provider").val().length; 


         if (username_length <1){ 

             $("#username_warning").append("Please select a provider"); 
         return false;
    }}
    else  {
        if(count<=1)
        {
            //alert(count+"less");
        count=1;
        }
        else
        {
            count=count-1;
            //alert(count+"grater");
        }
        //alert(count);
        $('#value').val(count);

        ///alert($('#value').val()+"count");

        //$("#value").value(count);
        //alert(    $("#value").value());
        makedate();

    }

}); 
$("#button").click(function() {
    $("#username_warning").empty(); 
    if($('#Provider').val()=="") {
        //alert("aaaa");

         var username_length; 

         username_length = $("#Provider").val().length; 


         if (username_length <1){ 

             $("#username_warning").append("Please select a provider"); 
         return false;
    }}
    else  {
        count=count+1;
        //alert(count);
        $('#value').val(count);

        ///alert($('#value').val()+"count");

        //$("#value").value(count);
        //alert(    $("#value").value());
        makedate();

    }










}); 

$('#date').change(function(){

//alert("change") ; 
    $('#value').val("0");
    count=0;
    //alert($('#value').val()+"change");
});
var select=false;
$("#appoinmentdate").live('click', function() {

     // alert("inside");
 select=true;

}); 
$("#reg").live('submit', function() {
    //alert("true0");
if(select== true){
    //alert("true");
}
else{
//$("#ps").attr("style=", "display: block;"); 
      return false; 

}

}); 



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue please?

Comment: i will reco. to use JQuery AJAX (can u debug in IE and show some ERR)

Comment: Yeah, since you're using jQuery, use the `$.ajax()` method to avoid any cross-browser inconsistencies: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: The only valid answer to a "not work(ing)" question is "you're doing something wrong" For starters; is there an error (press F12 in IE for debug tools)? Is it making the request? I think Aura could be right and you're creating the xhr object wrong but that seems to be the only code you didn't post. I agree with the previous comments that you should use $.ajax or $.post

Comment: @HMR while i am debugging in ie  iam getting a error message like     SCRIPT600: Invalid target element for this operation. 
basicnifo.js, line 95 character 12

Comment: @abhi Thank you for providing some more information. The line that causes that error is what line exatly in the code you posted? Maybe it's in 3rd party scripts so you can check the stack. In IE you can press F12, in the script tag there is a button "start debugging". When the error occures it should pause there, if it's in the code you posted please provide the line where it happens, if it's not in your code then check the "call stack" tab and go down the stack until you're in code that you wrote.

Comment: @HMR iam getting that error in the line     document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML = xmlHttpRequest.responseText; i dont knw what wrong with that code

Comment: @abhi not sure if you still have the problem but you can console.log(document.getElementById("divId") and console.log(xmlHttpRequest); see if either of them is null or undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't even try to debug those `makedate()` and `makedateStateHandler()` functions. They're just too much of a mess. If you wrote that code, sorry for the harsh words. If someone else wrote it, go kick them! :-)

Since you're already using jQuery, let's *use* it:

```
function makedate() {
    $('#button').attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajaXForgetdatesForAppoinment.jsp',
        data: {
            date: $('#date').val(),
            Location: $('#Location').val(),
            Provider: $('#Provider').val(),
            Appointmentdateformat: $('#Appointment').val(),
            value: $('#value').val()
        },
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function( data ) {
            $('#button').removeAttr( 'disabled' );
            $('#divId').html(data );
        },
        error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            // ...
        }
    });
}
```

This simple code replaces both those complicated functions. It should be pretty much a drop-in replacement, the one major difference being that it sends the POST data parameters in the POST body instead of the URL, in the usual fashion for POST requests. However, most server code should accept the data in either format.

jQuery makes this code simpler in several ways:

- Built-in `$.ajax()` instead of complicated `XMLHttpRequest` code.
- `.val()` to get `<select>`/`<option>` values.
- `$('#foo')` instead of `document.getElementById()`.

And one cosmetic point that is nonetheless very important: correct indentation! The indentation in the original code is all over the place. Proper indentation is very important for code readability.

After a second look at the code, you may be able to simply it even further. Since the data values you're sending with the POST come from the `#reg` form, you may be able to pick up all those values with a simple `.serialize()` call:

```
function makedate() {
    $('#button').attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajaXForgetdatesForAppoinment.jsp',
        data: $('#reg').serialize(),
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function( data ) {
            $('#button').removeAttr( 'disabled' );
            $('#divId').html( data );
        },
        error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            // ...
        }
    });
}
```

And that also makes it easy to move the data parameters into the URL if that's required by your server code:

```
function makedate() {
    $('#button').attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajaXForgetdatesForAppoinment.jsp?' +
             $('#reg').serialize(),
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function( data ) {
            $('#button').removeAttr( 'disabled' );
            $('#divId').html( data );
        },
        error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            // ...
        }
    });
}
```

Fair warning: Of course this is all untested code! But it should give you a good place to start.

Comment: I copied the above code ,but it is still not working  in ie 8,whilw i am clicking the button  request is not going to  ajaXForgetdatesForAppoinment.jsp  page

Comment: Which version of the code are you using? Is it actually calling this code? What do you get if you put some `console.log` calls in it? Or put in some `debugger` statements and look around in the debugger when it stops? I would expect that either (1) I got something wrong and it won't work in any browser, or (2) it will work in all browsers. I wouldn't expect that this code would work in other browsers but not in IE8.